# Add an "ALL" item to list of items in Parameter drop down

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am experimenting in PowerBI Paginated Reports and find the experience to be nearly identical to SSRS development.

So I'm bringing back a dataset borrowed from an existing Power BI solution.  I'd like to build a parameter to filter the results.  So I create some DAX to read just the unique combinations of two fields from the dataset for value and display.

I'd like to replicate an old trick where in SQL I would just union on a row with fields like "All" or "No Filter".  While I'm able to construct this analog in DAX Studio, it doesn't seem to be migrating well to Paginated reports.

```
EVALUATE
 (
    UNION (
        ROW ( "Plant Number", "ALL", "Plant Name", "All Plants" ),
        SUMMARIZE ( 'PLANT PR1', 'PLANT PR1'[Plant Number], 'PLANT PR1'[Plant Name] )
    )
)
```

That's the DAX that I can use in DAX studio, but when I put it in Paginated Reports as a data source for my 'Plant' Parameter, I get a bunch of nulls in the dropdown.  Any Ideas on how I could improve this to work in Reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back to this as it turned out to be just a very picky little problem with Report Builder's parsing.  I did replace `SUMMARIZE` with `ALL` as it seemed more appropriate for what I was doing, but the problem I was having actually had to do with the white space that was inserted by DAX Studio's 'format DAX' function.  Report Builder does not like that whitespace between the `EVALUATE` keyword and initial opening parentheses.  Once I snugged up the open paren to the end of `EVALUATE` everything worked fine.

```
EVALUATE(
    UNION (
        ROW ( "Plant Number", "All", "Plant Name", "<All Plants>" ),
        ALL ( 'PLANT PR1'[Plant Number], 'PLANT PR1'[Plant Name] )
    )
)
ORDER BY [Plant Name]
```